# Runtime Exception. Cannot evaluate lambda. Lambda workers cannot not start

Tags: python, lambda, sentiment-analysis, graphlab

i'm new to graphlab and python trying to work on an assignment,the question is do a sentiment analysis on selected words from that i'm supposed to create a new column for each of the selected words in the products matrix and the entry is the number of times such word occurs, so I created a function for the word "wordCount_select"

```
import graphlab
products = graphlab.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl')
products['word_count'] = graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(products['review'])
selected_words = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']
```

function

```
def wordCount_select(wc,selectedWord):
    if selectedWord in wc:
        return wc[selectedWord]
    else:
        return 0    


for word in selected_words:
    products[word] = products['word_count'].apply(lambda wc: wordCount_select(wc, word))
```

but im getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-494af1bfc2ab> in <module>()
      7 
      8 for word in selected_words:
----> 9     products[word] = products['word_count'].apply(lambda wc: wordCount_select(wc, word))

C:\Users\elginelijahsoft\Anaconda2\envs\dato-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sarray.pyc in apply(self, fn, dtype, skip_undefined, seed)
   1699 
   1700         with cython_context():
-> 1701             return SArray(_proxy=self.__proxy__.transform(fn, dtype, skip_undefined, seed))
   1702 
   1703 

C:\Users\elginelijahsoft\Anaconda2\envs\dato-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\cython\context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
     48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
     50             else:
     51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let exception propagate

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Cannot evaluate lambda. Lambda workers cannot not start.
```

any ideas what im doing wrong and why the lambda workers cannot start

Comment: Is this all there is too it? It feels like the RuntimeError should have a reason

Comment: @rainz this is what im getting

Comment: I'm also taking this course and I use GraphLab Create 1.8.5. I copied and pasted your code and used the amazon_baby.gl data, and it worked just fine... What is your version? Can you ```pip install -U graphlab-create```?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue during the Machine learning course. I have the latest Graphlab

I suspect this is a memory issue (not enough memory to load that data set and apply the lambda function). After closing most of the other stuff (browsers ...) the command ran fine.